# Stop itunes library from syncing with iphone automatically

Tags: macos, itunes, iphone

Is there a way I can stop my iphone from syncing with my itunes library automatically whenever I plug it in (without choosing to cancel the sync or quit itunes)? Ideally I'd love to be able to plug in my phone without itunes opening up in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iTunes, go to iTunes Menu > Preferences > click the "Devices Preferences" tab, and tick the "Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically" 
box.

[image]

This will stop iTunes from opening automatically when you plug in your iPhone.

You can also connect your iPhone to iTunes, stop the sync, click the iPhone icon in the upper left corner of the window, and in the "Options" section, untick "Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected".

[image]

This option prevents your specific phone from syncing automatically. You'll need to do both to get what you want accomplished.

Comment: Pro Tip - after you hit cmd/shift/4 if you then tap the space bar, you can take a neat pic of an entire window with a nice drop-shadow, just by clicking the appropriate window. I dropped one done like that into your answer, just so you can see how it looks.